# Sign Up and get Follow List With Instagram Still Allowed?

Tags: authentication, instagram, instagram-api

In my project I want to implement a sign up with Instagram and a get user's follow list feature. However, on the Instagram developer website under login permission it says under public content and follower list that "applications no longer accepted". Does this mean that I can no longer implement these features?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, a lot of Instagram API access was removed in 2016. You can read more about it here: http://uk.businessinsider.com/instagram-made-a-change-that-stopped-lots-of-third-party-apps-from-working-2016-6/?IR=T. This was to increase customer privacy.

Comment: That was in 2016, and this only happened recently. I've messaged instagram and they haven't released any information regarding this yet.

You can use them still in sandbox mode, but if your app gets approved, you won't be able to submit an application for these other api permissions, which means when you go live you can only get basic permissions access at this point.

Applications that have already been approved won't be effected by this.

This might mean they are changing policy or changing the way they handle submissions, but with no info, its all just speculation.

Comment: So will not be able to use their api for logging into my project and getting their follow list unless it's approved by Instagram?